# How to read XSD schema from different location(Jar) while validation

Tags: jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I want to marshall and unmarshall a xsd. I have a jar say A.jar which contains one xsd file say 1.xsd. I am trying to validate it by using  JAXB but it fails. 1.xsd is importing 3 more schema that is present in different jar (B. jar). How can I validate such that while validating it the 1.xsd could read the imported files that belongs to different jar  (B.jar).

Comment: " I am trying to validate it by using JAXB but it fails" - in what way does it fail, can you give any relevant code snippets or errors messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming both jars are available on the classpath, it doesn't really matter that much whether the schema files are spread over different jars or not. If one schema imports or includes another schema, what matters is that the path can be resolved.

Suppose you have a package `my.project.schemas` which exists in `A.jar` and `B.jar`. In `A.jar` that package contains `1.xsd`, which imports `2.xsd` in the same package in `B.jar`. If the import element in `1.xsd` looks like this...

```
<xs:import namespace="https://www.example.com" schemaLocation="2.xsd" />
```

then it should work. A resolver takes care of locating the other schema, and since the given `schemaLocation` is relative, the resolver will find it because it considers the same package across different jar files as the same location.

Things can get more complicated if there's different packages. In that case you'd need to use a relative path which may need to go up or down the package hierarchy to refer to the correct file (example: `additional/2.xsd` if package `additional` is a member of package `my.project.schemas`). Another option is to [use a custom resolver](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/SchemaFactory.html#setResourceResolver(org.w3c.dom.ls.LSResourceResolver)). This lets you intercept the calls for external resources and resolve them programmatically.

Finally, note that the `SchemaFactory` used for creating a `Schema` object [has a method that accepts an array of sources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/SchemaFactory.html#newSchema(javax.xml.transform.Source[])). If you create a `Source` for each schema file and supply all of them to the factory for creating a `Schema` object, this can avoid trouble with locations. In fact, you can just omit the `schemaLocation` attribute because the necessary references can be found among all the provided schemas.

In the past I've used JAXB with validating marshallers/unmarshallers that had to use schemas across different packages importing each other, which could also be across different jars. The last solution, providing a `Source` per schema to the factory method, was my preferred approach.